# NSApplicationWillTerminateNotification not Working

Tags: objective-c, nsnotification

My problem is that the `NSApplicationWillTerminateNotification` is not called when I quit my application. What I have tried: (appDelegate.m)

```
- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationWillTerminate:) name:NSApplicationWillTerminateNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification{
NSLog(@"quit");
}
```

OR

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSApplication *)application{
NSLog(@"Quit");
}
```

My application has no window, as it is a background application -> I deleted the window and the menu in interface Builder.

Comment: MacOSX as it is a background application and I use the "NS" prefix, not the "UI".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps in the background are terminated without any notification.

Comment: Is there any other way to determine if the app was terminated?